# Converting Json To XML Missing definitions

Tags: xml, json, visual-studio-2013

I have searched a lot about this all over the internet and I can't figure out why...

The header file `Newtonsoft.Json.Jsonconvert` does not have a definition for `DeserializeXmlNode()`
which I need to convert Json to Xml.

Also the `load()` doesn't have a definition either in `WIndows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument`

here are my references

```
.NET for windows store apps
BehavioursXamlSDKManaged
Newtonsoft.Json
Windows
```

//I know I have a lot of namespaces but it's because I've been trying a lot of code to fix my problem

here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;


namespace Project
{

    class JsonToXml
    {
        XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        private const string Uri = "https://www.thissite.com/api/list/0/";
        public string readlines;

        async public void ReadDataFromWeb()
        {
            var GetHyped = new Uri(Uri);
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
            var getHypedTask = client.GetAsync(GetHyped);
            await Task.WhenAll(getHypedTask);

            var GetHypedResp = getHypedTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            await Task.WhenAll(GetHypedResp);

            readlines = GetHypedResp.Result.ToString();

            //here is where the problem is
            XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(readlines);
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the version number of the dll you added; you can you that by clicking the Newtonsoft.Json dll and checking the Version property in the Properties window.
It should be 4.5.0.0 or higher. If that's not the case, make sure you have an up-to-date version of the dll.

Comment: I have the latest version. Downloaded from Nuget Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

XmlDocument doc = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(readlines);